# Cant Insert into database when upload [codeigniter]

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, file-upload

i trying to upload file but its still cant insert to database i dont know why, i've try many code but none of it working, much appreciate if you help me

here's my code :

```
    $upload_image_dp1 = $_FILES['upload_dp1']['name'];
    $upload_image_dp2 = $_FILES['upload_dp2']['name'];
    $upload_image_dp3 = $_FILES['upload_dp3']['name'];
    $upload_file_invoice = $_FILES['upload_invoice']['name'];

    if (!empty($upload_image_dp1) && !empty($upload_image_dp2) && !empty($upload_image_dp3) && !empty($upload_file_invoice)) {
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/uploads/dp/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']     = '10240';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        // $config2['upload_path'] = './assets/img/uploads/invoice/';
        // $config2['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
        // $config2['max_size']     = '10240';
        // $this->load->library('upload', $config2);

        $upload_dp1 = $this->upload->do_upload('upload_dp1');
        $file1 = $this->upload->data('file_name');
        $upload_dp2 = $this->upload->do_upload('upload_dp2');
        $file2 = $this->upload->data('file_name');
        $upload_dp3 = $this->upload->do_upload('upload_dp3');
        $file3 = $this->upload->data('file_name');
        $upload_invoice = $this->upload->do_upload('upload_invoice');
        $file4 = $this->upload->data('file_name');

        $this->db->set('upload_dp1', $file1);
        $this->db->set('upload_dp2', $file2);
        $this->db->set('upload_dp3', $file3);
        $this->db->set('upload_invoice', $file4);
        $this->db->where('id_user', $this->user['id_user']);
        $this->db->where('status', "Not Complete");
        $this->db->where('id_type', $id_type);
        $this->db->update('passanger');
```

Comment: Start by enabling error reporting to see if anything shows. Check your logs also.

Comment: Could you get your last executed query with `echo $this->db->last_query();` end of the `query` code and verify it with your `database` entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function upload()
{

    $upload_image_dp1 = $_FILES['upload_dp1']['name'];
    $upload_image_dp2 = $_FILES['upload_dp2']['name'];
    $upload_image_dp3 = $_FILES['upload_dp3']['name'];
    $upload_file_invoice = $_FILES['upload_invoice']['name'];


    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/uploads/dp/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']     = '10240';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $upload_dp1 = $this->upload->do_upload('upload_dp1');
    $file1 = $this->upload->data('file_name');
    $upload_dp2 = $this->upload->do_upload('upload_dp2');
    $file2 = $this->upload->data('file_name');
    $upload_dp3 = $this->upload->do_upload('upload_dp3');
    $file3 = $this->upload->data('file_name');
    $upload_invoice = $this->upload->do_upload('upload_invoice');
    $file4 = $this->upload->data('file_name');

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!empty($upload_image_dp1) && !empty($upload_image_dp2) && !empty($upload_image_dp3) && !empty($upload_file_invoice))
    {

        $uploaddata = array(
            'upload_dp1' => $file1,
            'upload_dp2' => $file2,
            'upload_dp3' => $file3,
            'upload_invoice' => $file4
        );

        $this->User_model->update(1,$uploaddata);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Successfully Insert Your Resume We Will Contact Shortly');

    }
    else
    {

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);

    }

}


===> MODEL

 public function update($id,$data)
{
    $this->db->where('id','1');
    $this->db->update('testingupload',$data);
}


Please Use your Where condition
```